# socket emit not working after reconnection

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am using socket io to develop a chat between web users. First time a user is logged in then connected to the server socket, I have no problems using a socket.io('INPUT_MESSAGE', data) event with the sender email, receiver email and message as data. Then I use the receiver email to get his socketId and finally I use a io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('OUTPUT_MESSAGE') event to send the message to the corresponding receiver.
So far i it works well. However, when I reset the server and the current connected clients connect again the "OUTPUT_MESSAGE" event does not work anymore... Any idea?

When a new client is connected to the socket (name is the email client):

```
socket.on('SEND_NAME_TO_SERVER', name => { 
serverNames = [...serverNames, { socketId: socket.id, name }];
});
```

New message from a client received:

```
socket.on('INPUT_MESSAGE',  data =>{   
let userSocket ="";  
const { message, user, sender,} = data;

 .....Add the new message to database....

for (let i = 0; i < serverNames.length; i++){
if (serverNames[i].name === user){                        
userSocket=serverNames[i].socketId;                       
io.sockets.connected[userSocket].emit("OUTPUT_MESSAGE_toUSER", data); 
)};
```